# Creating an order cart - clicking on "view cart" clears the session and reloads page?

Tags: php, mysql, session, compare

I am having problems with a simple script that allows a user to browse products drawn from a MySQL table.

The script has a "cart" function where the user can add specific items to an order. The user can then view the order which produces a list of specific items that were ordered, their price and a total amount. (later the user will be able to email the output to the website creator)

Here is the controller:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/config.php';
require_once($docRoot . '/includes/layout.php');
require_once($docRoot . '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php');

$productsQuery = 'SELECT `id`, `refCode`, `desc`, `pack`, `measure`, `quantity`, `deptCode`, `taxable`, `price1`, `price2`, `crdCode`, `cost1`, `cost2` FROM `products` ORDER BY `desc` ';
$productsSql = mysql_query($productsQuery) or die(mysql_error());

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['order']))
{
$_SESSION['order'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Order')
{
// Add item to the end of the $_SESSION['order'] array
$_SESSION['order'][] = $_POST['id'];
header('Location: .');
exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Clear order')
{
// Empty the $_SESSION['order'] array
unset($_SESSION['order']);
header('Location: ?order');
exit();
}

if (mysql_num_rows($productsSql) == 0)
{
die('No results.');
} else
{
$orderContent = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productsSql))
{
$prId = $row['id'];
$prRefCode = $row['refCode'];
$prDesc = $row['desc'];
$prPack = $row['pack'];
$prMeasure = $row['measure'];
$prQuantity = $row['quantity'];
$prDeptCode = $row['deptCode'];
$prTaxable = $row['taxable'];
$prPrice1 = $row['price1'];
$prPrice2 = $row['price2'];
$prCrdCode = $row['crdCode'];
$prCost1 = $row['cost1'];
$prCost2 = $row['cost2'];
$orderContent .= '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$prId.'</td>
        <td>'.$prDesc.'</td>
        <td>'.$prPack.'x'.$prSize.' '.$prMeasure.'</td>
        <td>R'.$prPrice1.'</td>
        <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$prId.'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Order" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>           
   </tr>
';

if (isset($_GET['order']))
{
$order = array();
$total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $id)
{
        foreach ($prId as $product)
        {
        if ($product == $id) 
            {
            $order[] = $product;
            $total += $prPrice1;
            break;
            }
        }

include($docRoot . '/orders/orders-finalize.php');
exit();

}
}
}}
include 'orders-layout.php';

?>
```

This is the include orders-finalize:

```
<?php
ob_start();

<meta name="keywords" content="'.$keyWords.'" />
';

$belowMenu = '
<p>Orders Page</p>
';

$pageContent = '
<h2>Your order</h2>
';
if (count($order) > 0)
{
    $pageContent .= '
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>R'.number_format($total, 2).'</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
';  
    foreach ($order as $item) 
{
    if ($item == $prId) 
    {
        $pageContent .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$prDesc.'</td>
                    <td>
                        R'.number_format($prPrice1, 2).'
                    </td>
                </tr>
';      
    }
}
    $pageContent .= '
        </tbody>
        </table>
';

} else
{ 
$pageContent .= '
<p>Your cart is empty!</p>
';
}

$pageContent .= '
<form action="?" method="post">
    <p>
        <a href="?">Continue shopping</a>
        or
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Clear order" />
    </p>
</form>
';


echo $head1 . $pageDetails . $head2 . $header . $menu . $belowMenu . $content . $pageContent . $footer . $pageScripts;
exit;
?>
```

This is the orders-layout include:

```
<?php
ob_start();

$belowMenu = '
<p>Orders Page</p>
';

$pageContent = '
<h2>Place your order</h2>
<p>Your order contains '.count($_SESSION['order']).' items.</p>
<p><a href="?order">View your order</a></p>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Stock Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Packsize</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
';

$pageContentEnd = '
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<p>All prices are inclusive of VAT</p>
';


echo $head1 . $pageDetails . $head2 . $header . $menu . $belowMenu . $content . $pageContent . $orderContent . $pageContentEnd . $footer . $pageScripts;
exit;
?>
```

This produces a page where each result is listed.

If the user clicks "view order", It should lead to a page where the user can see all the items that have been ordered.

What it actually does, is empty the session and refresh the page.

If anyone can spot where I am going wrong here, It would be appreciated if you could pass on some input!

Here is the code that the controller was based on:

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
    '/includes/magicquotes.inc.php';

$items = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'desc' => 'Canadian-Australian Dictionary',
            'price' => 24.95),
    array('id' => '2', 'desc' => 'As-new parachute (never opened)',
            'price' => 1000),
    array('id' => '3', 'desc' => 'Songs of the Goldfish (2CD set)',
            'price' => 19.99),
    array('id' => '4', 'desc' => 'Simply JavaScript (SitePoint)',
            'price' => 39.95));

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Buy')
{
// Add item to the end of the $_SESSION['cart'] array
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['id'];
header('Location: .');
exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Empty cart')
{
// Empty the $_SESSION['cart'] array
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
header('Location: ?cart');
exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['cart']))
{
$cart = array();
$total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id)
{
    foreach ($items as $product)
    {
        if ($product['id'] == $id)
        {
            $cart[] = $product;
            $total += $product['price'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

include 'cart.html.php';
exit();
}

include 'catalog.html.php';

?>
```

Here is the code for cart.html.php:

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
    '/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Shopping cart</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"
            content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1>
    <?php if (count($cart) > 0): ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>$<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($cart as $item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php htmlout($item['desc']); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        $<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p>Your cart is empty!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form action="?" method="post">
        <p>
            <a href="?">Continue shopping</a> or
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Empty cart"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: is including order finalize inside the foreach session a typo or is that how it is in your actual code?

Comment: Relative redirects like this: `header('Location: ?order');` are not legal, although they work in a lot of browsers. But especially this one where it's not even page is probably not recommended.

Comment: You need to call `session_start` before any output - maybe move it right to the top of the file (before any includes) to be sure?

Comment: @Dreaded It is not a typo, see my edit for the original script taken out of a sitepoint book.

Comment: @Ariel What do you mean not legal?

Comment: @Skilldrick It does not seem to make a difference. I can add items to the session, but when "view order" is clicked, it empties changes the session count to 0 then refreshs the page.

Comment: All `Location` urls must be absolute urls. i.e. including the http:// part. Yes, lots of browsers accept relative ones, but I would not rely on it, and I would especially not rely on a redirect that just changed the query parameters! BTW, using redirects for this type of flow control isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say this is not a typo introduced when pasting to stackoverflow, please see this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $id)
{
        foreach ($prId as $product)
        {
            if ($product == $id) 
            {
               $order[] = $product;
               $total += $prPrice1;
               break;
             }
        }

include($docRoot . '/orders/orders-finalize.php'); **//why this is included here? you are not yet looped to include all the orders from session inside order array**
exit();

}
```

see the line where I say why this is included here? you are not yet looped to include all the orders from session inside order array.   you are putting that line inside the foreach that loops through session that actually generate order array, yet in the included order finalize, you try to loop through the uncompleted orders

not sure if this gonna fix the problem you are having, but try to check this and let us know.

Comment: For the other issue, try to add session_write_close(); before header("location:.") after you add order to the session

Comment: O MY WORD!!! Okay, you were right! But that now takes me to a page where it displays "your cart is empty". On the original page, i added an item to the order, then clicked view order, but it seems to not be carrying the session over?

Comment: did you try to add session_write_close(); ? please see my above comment.

Comment: Yes I have added this. I think that maybe there is nothing being added to the $order array, or possibly the foreach and if on the finalize page, but i am not quite sure what.

Comment: try to debug the code using for example var_dump then put die() after suspected session one by one and see which one is not working properly to be sure. there are a lot of possibilities.  or you can make a function to record log in a file, and try to log outputs in each step

Comment: The array stored in $order is not getting carried over to the finalize page, this was assertained by a var_dump. Any ideas why?